# SSIS DTSX File Repair Tool

Tags: sql-server, validation, ssis

I'm working with an SSIS 2005 file that crashes Visual Studio 2005 on my workstation.  This happens when I open the data flow diagram and Visual Studio attempts to validate the package.  I can open it successfully on another computer though.  The package itself is fairly simple and only has two control flow tasks and maybe ten tasks in the data flow.

I'm wondering if there is a tool that goes through the XML in the dtsx file and repairs any issues or if this is even necessary.  The dtsx file is about 171 kB  and it seems like there's a lot in it considering what a simple package it is.

Comment: 1. Make sure you have all SP's installed on the computer
2. If it's simple - why not simply rebuild it?
3. Look in the code of dstx file via Notepad - sometimes it's obvious what is wrong - some weird symbols at the end or at the beginning

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem with a seemingly corrupt package crashing VS. Trying to analyze the xml directly is pretty painful, so through process of elimination, you might fix issues by doing things like moving one object in and out of a container, as this seems to fix issues with orphan references in the dtsx.

The "big red button" option is to recreate the package, which is less arduous than it sounds: you can just copy paste components between two VS sessions and you'll maybe discover the container causing the problem this way.

There's no tool to automate this unfortunately: SSIS is just an unfinished and quirky product.